# Import data from a pg dump file to MS SQL on centOS 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, centos7

I have a rails app on heroku and the database I am using on it is Postgres.
I want to restore data from a pg dump file that I get from heroku on an app locally deployed on centOS 7 which has database of MSSQL. Is there any proper way to do it? The solutions I found are mostly windows based softwares. The app is on ruby on rails, any help would be great.

Comment: Restore to PosgreSQL or MS SQL on CentOS 7? Please edit your question and add more information.

Comment: @Shameel is the question understandable now? Sorry about that.